# How to migrate spring-modules-validation @Expression to something newer?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-validator

How to migrate the following old spring-modules-validation 0.8a based to code to something newer like JSR-303/JSR-349/Hibernate/Spring based?

```
private String newPassword;


@Expression("newPassword == passwordConfirm")
private String passwordConfirm;
```